# nvidia-smi returns error on ubuntu 16.04 kernal 4.10.x

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Tried to install cuda driver 8.0 and toolkit 375 on ubuntu 16.04 with kernal 4.10, but keeps receiving this error. How should the nvidia driver and cuda toolkit be installed?

```
> nvidia-smi
> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running
```

Comment: You have not asked a question here. Also, how is this actually on-topic for [SO] anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out toolkit 375 doesn't work nicely with ubuntu kernal 4.10. (see [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/995429/failed-installed-nvidia-with-kernel-4-10/)). So the way to go, is to install driver from apt-get, and install toolkit from nvidia website's run file.

```
# 1. install nvidia driver from package manager
$ sudo apt install nvidia-375

# 2. install cuda toolkit from nvidia website
# IMPORTANT: no need to install driver here, since it's already installed in the previous step.
$ wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/local_installers/cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run
$ chmod +x cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run
$ mkdir installers
$ sudo ./cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux-run -extract=`pwd`/installers
$ cd installers
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.26.run
```

helpful link: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/27/setting-up-ubuntu-16-04-cuda-gpu-for-deep-learning-with-python/